# simple audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, sound

[image: this is the schematics]

I did this circuit in my protoboard, and it worked for a while, but the quality sound was terrible, and suddenly it stoped working. Can anyone explain me in which part of the circuit i did something wrong? any sugestions to improve the sound quality and make it work?

the transistors used are both BC546, and the microphone was acctually an input for an mp3 player, but i didn't found in the programam that i did the schematics, so i put i microphone.

Comment: Tell us what transistors you used and what type of microphone you used.

Comment: ok, i updated the description

Comment: dare I ask where that circuit idea came from?

Comment: i'm studying electronics and i thought that it would work this way, but as you can see i'm a very beginer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you forgot to power the amp.  Perhaps because of the double transistor gain stage, a little signal was making it onto the base of the first transistor.  Connect the 9 V supply to pin 6, and put a 100 nF to 1 µF ceramic bypass cap immediately accross the chip.

Depending on the microphone type, it may need a weak resistor to power with the other side grounded.  Electret mics work that way.  Your circuit should work with a dynamic or piezo mic.

This amp doesn't have a lot of gain, so whatever you get out of the speaker will probably not be that loud.  Still, even with a gain of 20 you should be able to hear something in the speaker when you brush your finger over the mic or tap on it.

Are you sure the 9 V supply is really 9 V after powering that speaker?  The way you have it set up, you are putting significant DC current thru the speaker.  With only 4 Ω, it could be trying to put nearly 1 A thru the speaker.  If the supply can't handle that, the voltage will collapse and the amp won't work as intended.

Comment: i powered the amp! just forgot to draw it, i'm sorry, but, about the capacitor, where exactly should i put it?

Comment: @Levi: The bypass cap should be as close as possible accross the power and ground pins of the amp.  If the amp was indeed powered, then that doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: ok, i understanded the problem now. I'm going to fix as soon as i buy the capacitor. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Levi: No, I don't think lack of a bypass cap explains the symptom.  Without a bypass cap the amp could possibly oscillate, but I don't think you'd get what you observed then.  There is still something else going on.  Did you look into the mic and the 9 V supply as I mentioned?

Comment: well, as i said in the description, i'm not using a mic, its a output of a mp3 player. Maybe, what's happening is that the input is AC and i can't activate the transistors with AC input.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit is DC-biased.  Some current is always flowing through the speaker all the time.  Let's figure out how much.

The datasheet claims "Self-centering output quiescent voltage" so let's assume the output DC voltage is 4.5 volts.

Now there will be two Si diode drops in the two output transistors.  Therefore the voltage across the speaker is 4.5 - 0.7 - 0.7 = 3.1 V.

The DC resistance of a loudspeaker is somewhat less than its rated impedance (which is measured at audio frequencies).  So let's say 3.5 ohms.

Therefore, the current through the speaker is 3.1V / 3.5 ohms, or 885 mA.  And the power dissipated in the second transistor is (9 - 3.1) * 0.885, or 5.22 W

The datasheet absolute maximum power dissipation for TO-92 transistors like BC546 is 500 mW.

If you exceed absolute maximum dissipation by a factor of 10, do not be surprised if your transistor elects a Pope.

Have you tried the LM386 on its own, with a blocking capacitor in place of the Darlington pair?  The '386 is a power amplifier, designed for driving loudspeakers directly.

Comment: ok, i did it, but the sound is distorting a lot! but less than before, with the Darlington pair. would it be because the amplifier have not so much power?

Comment: You won't get lots of power out, but the sound should be clean at low volumes.  Try grounding the (-) input like the datasheet suggests.

Comment: Distorting is what the LM386 chip does.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you exceeded the 100mA absolute max current rating of the BC546 transistor; or else its 0.5W power dissipation Either way, the transistor got hot, and it died.

Ironically the LM386 would do a reasonable (but not great - it's designed for 8 ohm and higher loads) job of driving the speaker without the transistors. Connect its output (pin 5) to the speaker via a 470uf capacitor, and omit the transistors completely..